# is requesting ad in onAdFailedToLoad is a good practice?

Tags: admob

I am using Admob and following code in my app with admob.
i want to know is this a good practice or not. as you can see my fill rate is very low.

```
adView.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAdFailedToLoad(int errorCode) {
                super.onAdFailedToLoad(errorCode);
                adView.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
            }
});
```

[image: Admob stats]

Answer (score 0):

Yes. The best way to counter a low fill rate is to use mediation so that you request an ad from another provider when your first doesn't have one. You can configure multiple networks.

See the Admob doco on mediation (It won't require any code changes).